# Is there a way to see the machine behind Sans' lab?

Tags: undertale

I recently found the lab that Sans has. However, I couldn't see what the machine looked like. Is there a way to see it?

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot see what the machine looks like.

Sans' Workshop is an unfinished and/or bonus part of the game and doesn't really impact the plot in any way. It has several mysterious objects which fans have theorized reference Gaster (the previous Royal Scientist) in some way. The machine under the cloth is believed to be a Gaster Blaster, the dragon-head-shaped laser guns Sans uses against you int he Genocide route. However, none of these theories have any concrete proof since Gaster is an unfinished character that can only be seen in-game by hacking your save file.

For more information about Sans' workshop, you can take a look at the [wiki page](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Papyrus_and_Sans%27s_House#Sans.27s_Workshop) on the subject.

Comment: Are you kidding? It has a HUGE impact on the plot, basically explains who sans is, and his family, and his friends! And you don't need to hack your save to see Gaster!

Comment: @Alex Well, it might, if you believe certain claims. Buuuut that's just a theory. A GAME THEORY! Thanks for reading!

Comment: @Alex The only known family that Sans has is Papyrus. Any other supposed family members are just speculation from fans (not confirmed by the game developer AFAIK). Also, Frisk doesn't recognize the people in the photos, so that doesn't help identify anyone either. So no, there's no  real plot relevance to the lab. As for seeing Gaster in-game, I know you have to have certain "Fun" levels set in your save file. I don't think you can achieve those Fun values legitimately without hacking your save, but I guess I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: @MageXy have you ever played the mother series? You would understand then

Comment: There was a [minor update](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Undertale/Changelog) to the game which among other things allows meeting Gaster legitimately.